# Const correctness of pointers against safe checks during initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

Consider a class that allocates a block of memory to use:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

class ByteBuffer
{
   byte* const m_begin; // const pointer, non-const data
   byte* const m_end;   // const pointer, non-const data
   byte* m_pData;       // a non-const pointer, e.g. write-head

public:
   ByteBuffer(size_t byteBufferSize)
   :  m_begin(new byte[byteBufferSize],
      m_end(m_begin + byteBufferSize),
      m_pData(m_begin)
   {}

   ~ByteBuffer() { delete[] m_begin; }
};
```

If I want the code maintained, it's nice to ensure that `m_begin` and `m_end` are `const` so as to ensure any math operations regarding the size of the container will be correct (and that someone else coming in won't accidentally update the edges. But the drawback is that I can no longer initialize the data anywhere outside of the constructor's initialization list.

Rare as `std::bad_alloc` may be, I'm not convinced that calling `new[]` like I did above is a good idea. So my question is: how would we deal with wanting `const` pointers to memory to be managed in a class?

I would want the constructor to do something akin to this:

```
: m_begin(nullptr), m_end(nullptr), m_pData(nullptr)
{
     // initialize here
     // if initialization is successful, set const & non-const ptrs
}
```

Am I overthinking this? Does making `m_begin` a `const unique_ptr` make all the initialization woes go away somehow?

Comment: IMO having const data members is more trouble than it's worth; e.g. the class cannot be made  Assignable.

Comment: In your final code block, the important question is what do you want to do if initialization is *not* successful?

Comment: @M.M: that's a good point.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have never ever hit a `bad_alloc` at all, and I'm not convinced that I can recover gracefully in my use case, which means that I would want to percolate the error condition somehow. If that is impossible with `const` data members & calling `new` in initialization, the decision is then made for me. :)

Comment: @ilzxc "*I would want to percolate the error condition somehow*" - you do that by simply letting the error happen and have the caller of the constructor deal with it as needed. There is no reason not to use the member initialization list as you showed. If you want your constructor to react to (but not suppress) an allocation error, you can always use a [function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a fair solution. If, in turn, I wanted to suppress the error, would `new (std::nothrow) byte[byteBufferSize]` help to ensure that `m_begin` is `nullptr` on failed initialization?

Comment: You want an exception thrown on failed initialization. If you allow the class to be created with nullptr then every time you ever use one of these classes you have to do null pointer checks and take action if they fail, which complicates your code.

Comment: @M.M But if it is assignable, you have to implement copy… And at that point, it is early enough to remove `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is essentially the correct way to write it. However, you could consider using `std::vector` instead as you won't have to explicitly manage memory.

If fact, `std::vector` already define `begin()` and `end()` (which would replace `m_pData` in your code) and you won't really need `m_end` replacement as you don't manage the memory yourself.

The equivalent would be `begin() + capacity()` but as element are not initialized after `end` you should not access those anyway (probably undefined behavior from language point of view).

Otherwise small improvements are possible like:

- Avoid m_ for member variable name. Not much useful.
- Avoid p prefix for pointer to data.
- In the initialization list, put comma on the beginning of a line (as you have done for :) instead of at the end of previous line. It make it easier to add, remove, move or comment out items when done that way.
- If you don't want your object to be moveable or copyable, it is preferable to explicitly specify it:

  ```
  public:
      ByteBuffer(const ByteBuffer &) = delete;
      ByteBuffer(ByteBuffer &&) = delete;
      ByteBuffer &operator=(const ByteBuffer &) = delete;
      ByteBuffer &operator=(ByteBuffer &&) = delete;
  ```

Alternatively, you could also use `std::unique_ptr` and then you won't have to free memory yourself. This could be useful when you class need to make multiple allocations or when an exception could be thrown after the allocation in the constructor.

The best solution really depends on what you want to do with your `ByteBuffer` class or even if you really need such a class (as you might use `std::vector` directly instead or doing a simple alias like:

```
using ByteBuffer = std::vector<unsigned char>;
```

If fact, the `byte typedef` might not even be that much useful if you use `auto` for your loops and iterators.

Speaking of `const`, I would generally recommend to have it to prevent undesired changes. However, sometime you need to reset those pointers to `nullptr` during destruction of somewhat complex classes where there could be some mutual destruction for example.

So by having simple classes that respect the **SRP** (single responsabilty principle), you essentially avoid that kind of problems.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding giving unsolicited critique, particularly in uncertain contexts.

Comment: Hungarian notation is company policy, alignment of variables & spacing of the constructor initialization list is also. I removed everything from the class except for things I had a question about. Why you would recommend a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array` for this use case baffles me. (I'm not using a vector since I want my memory to be static enough for `const`ness of begin & end to be guaranteed...)

Comment: If you don't want to improve your coding… then it is up to you. However, even if you have to code with obsolete things like Hungarian notation, you don't have to use on the web. At least, it would should that you care about modern practices and help your reputation.

Comment: If you example, the size is dynamic (pass to the constructor) so `std::array` would not apply as the dimension would need to be known at compile time. **Constness** of `end` does not make much sense as you actual size vary (i.e `m_pData`).